# mpirun fails to recognize program in $PATH

Tags: path, mpi

Somehow `mpirun` fails to acknowledge my `$PATH`. The program `PyroDist`, that I have in `$PATH`, works:

```
$ PyroDist
Can't find asked option -in
PyroDist - pairwise distance matrix from flowgrams
-in     string            flow file name
-out    stub              out file stub
Options:
-ni                       no index in dat file
-rin    string            lookup file name
```

And running it with `mpirun` and full path works too:

```
$ mpirun -np 4 ../bin/PyroDist -in C005.dat -out foo
0: Read data
0: Broadcast data
0: Broadcast flows
nN=2094 nM=360 nSize=753840
```

But this fails:

```
$ mpirun -np 4 PyroDist
Missing: program name
Program PyroDist either does not exist, is not 
executable, or is an erroneous argument to mpirun.
```

Since I am going to use a complex set of workflows it is not feasible to use full paths. Any ideas?

(openmpi 1.2.7 on Linux 2.6.32)

Answer (score 5):

`mpirun` probably uses an `execv()` call to run the program instead of an `execvp()` one (which would search for it in `PATH`).

First workaround: ask the shell to lookup for the command by itself:

```
mpirun -np 4 $(which PyroDist) -in C005.dat -out foo
```

Otherwise: two (not so good) workarounds I can think of:

1. Use `/usr/bin/env` with argument `PyroDist`, but this requires that `mpirun` allows to pass arguments along with the program somehow.
2. Write your own wrapper like:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   PyroDist
   ```

   and place it somewhere with a “fixed” relative path.

Comment: Can I somehow confirm that the 'problem' is with `execv()` contra `execvp()`? I would prefere a recompile of mpi to support the latter, if that helps. The suggested work-arounds will not help me since this is only one bit of a large framework (QIIME) and there is a _lot_ of programs like PyroDist and also, mpirun is tucked away inside multiple wrappers.

Comment: It strikes me that openmpi 1.2.7 is quite old. On another machine running openmpi 1.4.1 there is no problem.

Comment: Updating to 1.4 solved the problem (too bad I am not allowed to answer my own question - now someone can beat me to it! ;o)

Comment: Ok glad you could solve it!

Comment: @Martin You can answer your own question, you just need to wait a bit (by now, you should be able to do it).